# Programatically allow uknown sources in appium for android application

Tags: python, android, appium

I am using python and appium to test an android application in android emulator, the apk file is pre-installed using following capabilities:

```
capabilities = dict(
platformName='Android',
automationName='uiautomator2', 
deviceName='Nexus',
appPackage='co.codemind.package.com', 
language='en',
locale='US', 
app='files/app.apk',
)
```

When there is an update for the app the popup for update/download appears and after it there is another popup to allow unknown sources even if the app is installed.

Is it possible to specify in capabilities to allow unknown sources?

I know there is option to allow all the popups but it doesn't work for me beacuse I need to specify some popups not allow them blindly.